# Render view Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How do you render a view file in the profile module's index view file. I tried this:

`<?=$this->render('/product/product/_search')?>`

This is the error I get:

> The view file does not exist: C:\OpenServer\domains\zuppermart\frontend\modules\profile\views\product/product/_search.php`

I also tried `<?=$this->render('//product/product/_search')?>`

And I get this error:

> The view file does not exist: C:\OpenServer\domains\zuppermart\frontend\modules\profile\views\profile\modules//product/product/_search.php

Comment: What is the actial view path? And from where you are trying to render it?

Comment: `C:\OpenServer\domains\zuppermart\frontend\modules\product\views\product\_search.php`
 this is actual path of search view file

Comment: And from where you are trying to render it?

Comment: if your partial view located in same folder with view that calling it, it should called by the name. ex : `<?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model]) ?>`

Comment: my _search.php is located in frontend/modules/product/views/product/

i want to render it in frontend/modules/profile/views/profile/index.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to given paths, it should be like this (absolute path specified via alias):

```
<?= $this->render('@frontend/modules/product/_search') ?>
```

But note that you are trying to render view from another module, I think it's better to create widget instead.

**Official docs:**

- [View render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#render%28%29-detail)
- [Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html)

Comment: `The view file does not exist: C:\OpenServer\domains\zuppermart\frontend\modules\profile\views\profile\product/_search.php` i have this error

Comment: Corrected the answer.

Comment: i tryed this an it works `<?= $this->render('@frontend/modules/product/views/product/_search') ?>`

Comment: try this one for Yii2 Basic and also working fine for advanced fronted `<?= $this->render('@app/views/product/_list');`

Answer (score 1):

in yii2, we can use ***render*** like this :
`$this->render('contact',['model'=>$model]);`

and ***render partial***:
`Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('myview');`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this kind views error is to use views base path 
i.e by using @app/views/:
`<?=$this->render('@app/views/product/product/_search')?>`